# How to escape backslashes to have safe strings ? php

Tags: php, escaping, octal, addslashes

i am stuck in this question since yesterday, i just want to understanding how to escape strings correctly, i didn't found any full answer.

here is my issue  =>

i have tow files:

1. replacement.txt , here is the content:

   new_content '\0020'
2. subject.txt , here is the content:

   structure old_content

here is my code:

```
$myfile = fopen ( __DIR__ . '/replacement.txt', "r" ) or die ( "Unable to open file!" );
$replacement = fread ( $myfile, filesize ( __DIR__ . '/replacement.txt' ) );
fclose ( $myfile );


    $myfile = fopen ( __DIR__ . '/subject.txt', "r" ) or die ( "Unable to open file!" );
    $subject = fread ( $myfile, filesize ( __DIR__ . '/subject.txt' ) );
    fclose ( $myfile );

    $subject = preg_replace ( "%structure.*%s", $replacement, $subject, - 1, $count );
    die ( $subject );
```

this code should print : `new_content '\0020'` but it prints `new_content 'structure old_content20'` .why? because there is a backslash that not escaped.

here is what i did but there is no luck :(

- i had tried to add `$replacement = addslashes($replacement);` before `preg_replace`: but here is what i got:`new_content \'\0020\'`, incorrect because there is a backslashed before quotes.
- i had tried strip slash the previous result `$subject = stripslashes ( $subject )`,  but here is what i got: `new_content '020'` , incorrect !

---

the only thing that worked for me, is to edit the `replacement.txt` to this :
`new_content '\\0020'`. but i can't change that manually , because it's an input from the user.

---

i don't think that the problem with the backslash , because if i change the `replacement.txt` to `new_content '\anyAlaphbetCharacter'` the above code (without addslahes and stripslash) will print : `new_content '\anyAlaphbetCharacter'` and that's correct.

please help me to understand what's going on ?and what the solution ?

Comment: @Uchiha you could see that i'v already use it , but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you one trick that is to replace `\` with some special word like `[backslash]` before preg_replace to avoid any problem with it

`$replacement = str_repalce(`\`, `[backslash]`, $replacement);`

then replace it back after preg_replace call

`$subject = str_repalce(`[backslash]`,`\`,$subject);`

Comment: thank you fro your answer, yes that's works , but i am searching for the correct solution, i mean without using tricks.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on. I think php defines `\0` simbol as `"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.`

Try use preg_quote() function.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but preg_quote() will escape other character like { ) ... and that's not good.